# How to update docker with wheel in local disk?

Tags: python, docker

In my company there is a docker (in the company local registry) I want to inherit from, while upgrading one of python packages.

The python package (with all its dependencies) is located at     `~/myPips/`

In the command line I can install it (when I open the terminal in     `~/myPips/`) in this way:

```
pip install comp-tnt
```

How can I write a Dockerfile which will inherit from the company base image and upgrade the python package which is located in my local folder?

I have tried to write something like:

Dockerfile.base-com-2:

```
FROM factory=registry:3000/base-com:v1
pip install -U ???
```

but how can I set the install from     `~/myPips/`?

(After I will write the dockerfile I want to create new docker with the command:
`docker build -f Dockerfile.base-com-2`)

Comment: What exactly do you have in `myPips`? You can use `-v` to expose individual directories inside Docker as mount points but whether this helps depends on what's in that directory.

Comment: You need to copy the wheel file into your host's build directory, then `COPY` it into the image, and then you can `RUN pip install` as normal.